# Tree Traversal Algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I have this json data model as an input:

```json
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "text": "Third message, which is a question",
            "id": "A",
            "from": "bot"
        },
        {
            "text": "A possible answer from the player",
            "id": "B",
            "from": "player"
        },
        {
            "text": "Another possible answer from the player",
            "id": "C",
            "from": "player"
        },
        {
            "text": "Let's continue here",
            "id": "D",
            "from": "bot"
        },
        {
            "text": "Or let's continue there",
            "id": "E",
            "from": "bot"
        },
        {
            "text": "Final message",
            "id": "F",
            "from": "bot"
        },
        {
            "text": "Second message",
            "id": "G",
            "from": "bot"
        },
        {
            "text": "First message",
            "id": "H",
            "from": "bot"
        }
    ],
    "edges": [
        {
            "id": "986c8f1fa8579f27",
            "fromNode": "G",
            "toNode": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": "94a3c66c65bd23f7",
            "fromNode": "A",
            "toNode": "B"
        },
        {
            "id": "7b6cb44465c55e11",
            "fromNode": "A",
            "toNode": "C"
        },
        {
            "id": "0c6880a58da67e1e",
            "fromNode": "B",
            "toNode": "D"
        },
        {
            "id": "f4451611cc94a7fe",
            "fromNode": "C",
            "toNode": "E"
        },
        {
            "id": "e81c1b1cb31a4659",
            "fromNode": "D",
            "toNode": "F"
        },
        {
            "id": "cda64626f98c3674",
            "fromNode": "E",
            "toNode": "F"
        },
        {
            "id": "f67f1d371ffbb169",
            "fromNode": "H",
            "toNode": "G"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is what I want to get as an output:

```json
{
    "chats": {
        "H": {
            "messages": [
                "First message",
                "Second message",
                "Third message, which is a question"
            ],
            "answer_propositions": {
                "D": "A possible answer from the player",
                "E": "Another possible answer from the player"
            }
        },
        "D": {
            "messages": [
                "Let's continue here",
                "Final message"
            ],
            "answer_propositions": {}
        },
        "E": {
            "messages": [
                "Or let's continue there",
                "Final message"
            ],
            "answer_propositions": {}
        }
    }
}
```

This data structure models a conversation between a bot (in red) and a player (in green):

[image]

- When the player select a message from `answer_propositions`, the message's `id` represent the next hop of the conversation.
- If the bot send multiple messages at once, those a grouped together in a single object with all messages part of an array.
- If we reach the end of the conversation, the player cannot provide any more answer so `answer_propositions` is empty.
- `nodes`'s object order cannot be used as the messages in the conversation tree can be created in a different order that the messages will be displayed.
- Performance is not an issue, it's ok if that's not a O(1) or O(log n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first convert the graph information in an adjacency list (keyed by `id`). Then compress nodes that are in a parent-child relationship and have `from` equal to `"bot"`, and do this recursively for each bot-player sequence.

Here is a possible implementation:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, text, source):
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.source = source
        self.children = []

def adjacenylist(graph):
    adj = {
        node["id"] : Node(node["id"], node["text"], node["from"])
        for node in graph["nodes"]
    }
    roots = set(adj)
    for edge in graph["edges"]:
        adj[edge["fromNode"]].children.append(adj[edge["toNode"]])
        roots.discard(edge["toNode"])
    if len(roots) != 1: 
        raise ValueError(f"Expected exactly one root, got {len(roots)}")
    for root in roots:
        return adj[root]

def mergenodes(root, result=None):
    if not result:
        result = {}
    key = root.id
    if key in result:
        return  # Already visited
    result[key] = {}
    messages = []
    while root.children and root.children[0].source == "bot":
        if len(root.children) > 1:
            raise ValueError("Unexpected: bot has more than one bot child")
        messages.append(root.text)
        root = root.children[0]
    messages.append(root.text)
    answer_propositions = {}
    for child in root.children:
        if len(child.children) != 1 or child.children[0].source != "bot":
            raise ValueError("Unexpected: player does not have exactly one child or it is not a bot response")
        mergenodes(child.children[0], result) # recurse
        answer_propositions[child.children[0].id] = child.text
    result[key] = { "messages": messages, "answer_propositions": answer_propositions }
    return result;

# Example from question:
graph = {"nodes": [{"text": "Third message, which is a question","id": "A","from": "bot"},{"text": "A possible answer from the player","id": "B","from": "player"},{"text": "Another possible answer from the player","id": "C","from": "player"},{"text": "Let's continue here","id": "D","from": "bot"},{"text": "Or let's continue there","id": "E","from": "bot"},{"text": "Final message","id": "F","from": "bot"},{"text": "Second message","id": "G","from": "bot"},{"text": "First message","id": "H","from": "bot"}],"edges": [{"id": "986c8f1fa8579f27","fromNode": "G","toNode": "A"},{"id": "94a3c66c65bd23f7","fromNode": "A","toNode": "B"},{"id": "7b6cb44465c55e11","fromNode": "A","toNode": "C"},{"id": "0c6880a58da67e1e","fromNode": "B","toNode": "D"},{"id": "f4451611cc94a7fe","fromNode": "C","toNode": "E"},{"id": "e81c1b1cb31a4659","fromNode": "D","toNode": "F"},{"id": "cda64626f98c3674","fromNode": "E","toNode": "F"},{"id": "f67f1d371ffbb169","fromNode": "H","toNode": "G"}]}

result = mergenodes(adjacenylist(graph))
print(result)
```

Here is the same in a JavaScript snippet:

```js
function adjacenyList({nodes, edges}) {
    const adj = Object.fromEntries(nodes.map((node) => [node.id, { ...node, children: [] }]));
    const roots = new Set(Object.keys(adj));
    for (const {fromNode, toNode} of edges) {
        adj[fromNode].children.push(adj[toNode]);
        roots.delete(toNode);
    }
    if (roots.size != 1) throw "Expected exactly one root, got " + roots.size;
    for (const root of roots) return adj[root];
}

function mergeNodes(root, result={}) {
    if (root.id in result) return; // Already visited
    const node = { messages: [] };
    result[root.id] = node;
    while (root.children[0]?.from == "bot") {
        if (root.children.length > 1) throw "Unexpected: bot has more than one bot child";
        node.messages.push(root.text);
        root = root.children[0];
    }
    node.messages.push(root.text);
    node.answer_propositions = Object.fromEntries(
        root.children.map(child => {
            if (child.children.length != 1 || child.children[0].from != "bot") {
                throw "Unexpected: player does not have exactly one child or it is not a bot response"
            }
            mergeNodes(child.children[0], result); // recurse
            return [child.children[0].id, child.text];
        })
    );
    return result;
}

// Example from question:
const graph = {"nodes": [{"text": "Third message, which is a question","id": "A","from": "bot"},{"text": "A possible answer from the player","id": "B","from": "player"},{"text": "Another possible answer from the player","id": "C","from": "player"},{"text": "Let's continue here","id": "D","from": "bot"},{"text": "Or let's continue there","id": "E","from": "bot"},{"text": "Final message","id": "F","from": "bot"},{"text": "Second message","id": "G","from": "bot"},{"text": "First message","id": "H","from": "bot"}],"edges": [{"id": "986c8f1fa8579f27","fromNode": "G","toNode": "A"},{"id": "94a3c66c65bd23f7","fromNode": "A","toNode": "B"},{"id": "7b6cb44465c55e11","fromNode": "A","toNode": "C"},{"id": "0c6880a58da67e1e","fromNode": "B","toNode": "D"},{"id": "f4451611cc94a7fe","fromNode": "C","toNode": "E"},{"id": "e81c1b1cb31a4659","fromNode": "D","toNode": "F"},{"id": "cda64626f98c3674","fromNode": "E","toNode": "F"},{"id": "f67f1d371ffbb169","fromNode": "H","toNode": "G"}]};

const result = mergeNodes(adjacenyList(graph));
console.log(result);
```